# How to write an array to do all the setter things in php?

Tags: php, oop

For example, I have a object like this:

```
class myObj{
 private $a;
 private $b;

 //getter , setter

}
```

And I would like to do something like:

```
$myObj = initWitharray(array('a'=> 'myavalue', 
                           'b'=> 'mybvalue'));
```

And the myObj will have all the a value and b value. How can I do so ? Thank you.

Comment: Since you need access to `myObj`'s private variables, this init method should really be a member of the class.

Comment: If you want to use your object like an array, why don't you consider using the PHP built-in Iterator interface ? http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NullUserException suggested:

```
<?php

class myObj {

    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function initWithArray(array $arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

}

// usage
$myObj = new myObj();
echo $myObj->initWithArray(array(
            'a' => 'myavalue',
            'b' => 'mybvalue'))
        ->get('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function initWithArray(array $a){
 $myObj = new myObj();

  foreach($a as $k => $v){
   $myObj->$k = $v;
 }

 return $myObj;
}

class myObj {
 private $a;
 private $b;

 public function __set($name, $value) {
   $this->$name = $value;
 }

 public function __get($name){
   if($this->$name != null)
     return $this->$name;

   return null;
 }
}
```

Or, as said in the comments, it's better if init function would be a member of a class.

Comment: It's worth noting that in `__get()`, `$name` can't be `null` (or empty for that matter). It is *always* a string.

Comment: $this->$name can be if you're accessing undefined property.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
class myObj {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    function __construct($passedArray){
        $this->a = array_key_exists('a', $passedArray) ? $passedArray['a'] : 'default_value_for_a';
        $this->b =  array_key_exists('b', $passedArray) ? $passedArray['b'] : 'default_value_for_b';
    }
//Rest of the code
}
```

Then:

```
newObj = new myObj(array('a'=> 'myavalue', 'b'=> 'mybvalue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the class constructor to pass in options when you create a new object. Doing it this way, you should also separate out the `setOptions` method so you can update the options after init as well.

Use this class like this: (shows both ways to set options)

```
$object = new myClass(array('a'=>'foo'));
$object->setOptions(array('b'=>'bar'));
```

Also, try not to confuse **object** with **class**. An object is an *instance* of a class.

```
class myClass
{
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function __construct(array $options = null)
    {
        if (null !== $options) {
            $this->setOptions($options);
        }
    }

    public function setOptions(array $options)
    {
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($this->$key)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: can I calling this...                $this->set_$key = $value; Because, I implement my own setter.

Comment: you can have as many other methods in there as you need. If you define a `set_a()` method, you can absolutely call `$this->set_a($value)`

Answer (score 0):

I usually adopts the approach which gives me total control over the object, like allowing someone to access the property. denying the permission, allowing access to only those which i think is appropriate according to application etc. and that's the purpose of object.

Have a look at the example below.

**Example**

```
class MyObj {

    private $data = array('one' => null, 'two' => null);

    public function __set($property, $value) {
        //Only allow to set those properties which is declared in $this->data array
        if(array_key_exists($property, $this->data)) {
            return $this->data[$property] = $value;
        } else {
            //if you want to throw some error.
        }
    }

    //you can allow or disallow anyone from accessing the class property directly.
    public function __get($property) {
        //To deny the access permission, simply throw an error and return false.
        $error = 'access denied to class property {' . $property . '}';
        return false;
        //Or Else Allow permission to access class property
        //return $this->data[$property];
    }
}
```

the above example demonstrates on how you can gain more control over the class property, by declaring class property `$data` as private you are basically disallowing anyone to do any sort of manipulation on the class property directly. whatever operation is to be carried out is done through PHP's getter `__get()` and setter `__set()` method. of course you can modify the above code according to your need, you just new a very few line of changes and it will behave the way you want it to.